# Javascript simple slider : how to deactive dragging on mouseMove

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple slider in Javascript.

First I create a DIV and append an image that represents the "blank" state of the slider. The DIV reacts to mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove. Each time mousedown is fired, an event listener is set to mousemove (to adjust the slider according to the coordinates of the mouse), and when mouseup is fired, the event listener is removed.

There's another image in the DIV, overlapping the first one. It expands and represents the slider.

The problem is that when I click on the DIV and start to move the mouse, it reacts like it wants me to drag something. Maybe it's the picture (the blank state). I get the "can't drop here" icon looking like a wrong way sign.

How to get rid of that ? I could paste some methods of the slider but it's not very relevant to the issue...

---

So here is the complete code of the slider :

volCont is the container DIV, volGauche the left extremity of the slider, volDroite the right one, volMilieu the main blank picture, and volPx is the picture that represents the slider (originally 1 pixel wide, expands all the way)

```
this.createVolBar = function()
{
    var volCont = document.createElement("DIV");
    volCont.id = "volCont";
    volCont.style.position = "absolute";
    volCont.style.left = "168px";
    volCont.style.top = "206px";
    volCont.style.width = "89px";
    volCont.style.height = "20px";

    var volGauche = document.createElement("IMG");
    volGauche.id = "volBarGauche";
    volGauche.style.position = "absolute";
    volGauche.style.left = "3px";
    volGauche.style.top = "6px";
    volGauche.style.width = "3px";
    volGauche.style.height = "9px";
    volGauche.src = plugImg.volGaucheOff;
    volCont.appendChild(volGauche);

    var volDroite = document.createElement("IMG");
    volDroite.id = "volBarDroite";
    volDroite.style.position = "absolute";
    volDroite.style.left = "83px";
    volDroite.style.top = "6px";
    volDroite.style.width = "3px";
    volDroite.style.height = "9px";
    volDroite.src = plugImg.volDroiteOff;
    volCont.appendChild(volDroite);

    var volMilieu = document.createElement("IMG");
    volMilieu.id = "volMilieu";
    volMilieu.style.position = "absolute";
    volMilieu.style.left = "6px";
    volMilieu.style.top = "6px";
    volMilieu.style.width = "77px";
    volMilieu.style.height = "9px";
    volMilieu.src = plugImg.volMilieu;
    volCont.appendChild(volMilieu);

    var volPx = document.createElement("IMG");
    volPx.id = "volPx";
    volPx.style.position = "absolute";
    volPx.style.left = "6px";
    volPx.style.top = "6px";
    volPx.style.width = "30px";
    volPx.style.height = "9px";
    volPx.src = plugImg.volBarPx;
    volCont.appendChild(volPx);

    // slide
    volCont.addEventListener('mousedown', that.startSlide, false);  
    volCont.addEventListener('mouseup', that.stopSlide, false);

    that.volCont = volCont;
    that.volPx = volPx;
    that.volMilieu = volMilieu;
    that.volGauche = volGauche;
    that.volDroite = volDroite;

    this.plugBox.appendChild(volCont);
};
```

And here are the sliding methods :

```
this.startSlide = function(event)
{
    var set_perc = (event.clientX - that.volCont.offsetLeft) / (that.volCont.offsetWidth);
    that.setSlide(set_perc);
    that.volCont.addEventListener('mousemove', that.moveSlide, false);
};

this.moveSlide = function(event)
{
    var set_perc = (event.clientX - that.volCont.offsetLeft) / (that.volCont.offsetWidth);
    that.setSlide(set_perc);
};

this.stopSlide = function(event)
{
    var set_perc = (event.clientX - that.volCont.offsetLeft) / (that.volCont.offsetWidth);
    that.setSlide(set_perc);
    that.volCont.removeEventListener('mousemove', that.moveSlide, false);
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example of your issue—[learn how to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If there is no code, it is impossible to troubleshoot.